# Get coordinates of a property from post meta data and show it on map in WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, arraylist

In my WordPress code I have a post type called property, in that post type we enter coordinates for property location, by getting that coordinates from  post meta data of post show it on Google Map.

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var locations = [
  ['Tambark Corner', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['HiddenMeadow', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['DOWN AVENUE', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['QUEENS WAY', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['RANDALL CLOSE', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
</script>
```

I want to get var locations=[] dynamically from post metadata. I tried different ways but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Yes dynamically define var locations=[] .You are correct.But

Comment: add ajax function that retrive the data in the success method assign the locations 
in foreach loop   like var locate = {lname: data.location,lat: data.latitute,lon:data.longitude} then locations.push(locate); but in for loop               position: new google.amps.LAtLng(locations[i].lat,locations[i].lon)

Comment: can you explain it clearly ,i don't know much about ajax..

Comment: First take json data from the database by ajax call or angular or some thing else

Comment: Then in foreach loop add the array by push method to locations array.Again in stated of for loop use foreach loop for marker